# How to convert a pdf to jpeg using ImageMagick and php

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagemagick-convert

I'm having a hard time converting a pdf file to jpg using the php Imagick Library on a wordpress based web site.

I have done some reading and I think I need to install Ghostscript to achieve my goal.
Is that the case or I can do it without Ghostscript.

My code looks like that:

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->setResolution(200,350);
$img->readImageFile($link.'[0]');
$img->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$img->destroy();
$img->clear();
```

I can successfully run the above code without the setImageFormat. setImageFormat produces an error. All other commands run successfully though.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install GhostScript. PDF is handled by the GhostScript interpreter.

Comment: Thanks I'm already doing so. I will vote your answer once everything works.

Comment: Apparently the hosting provider cannot install Ghostscript for security reasons since it uses shell_exec() and exec() and since it is on a shared hosting plan and safe_mode is on. So I guess I'm looking for an alternative solution. Any help??

Comment: Not very helpful I know but I suggest changing hosts.

Comment: I mainly know commercial alternatives, but even there being able to use exec or shell_exec is a necessity I'm afraid...